# T-SQL (trigger): update inserted record with data from another inserted record?

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

Is it possible to update a record in one table from a record being inserted into another table, using a trigger?

I have 4 tables: Purchase_order, Notes, PO_Address, table Address

I want to update table Notes with an adress from table Address.

If I create a new Purchase_order with notes on it, a record in table Notes will also be created automaticly. Notes has foreign key from Purchase_order.

If also the Purchase_order has an delivery address from table Address, another record will be created in PO_Address table with foreign keys from Purchase_order and Address.

What I want to do is: Create a trigger that can append the Address on the Note.

My problem is: Trying to join on PO_Address, but either Purchase_order or Note is not saved to the db yet, so I get null error. "Not possible to update Note with null".

I've tried to create the trigger on most of the different tables, but I don't know which table is updated last, so it fails...

It works for update, but problem is when a new purchase_order is created.

Example code:

```
USE [Mydatabase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create trigger [dbo].[_Note_Address] 
on  [dbo].[Note]
after insert, update
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    update Note
    set text = text + ---adress here
    from address a
    join ... ---and so on.
    where note_id in (select note_id from inserted) 
end
```

Sample data:

```
[Purchase_order]
ID____|TotalAmount
1     |300
2     |900
5     |1200

[Address]
ID____|Street___
10    | One Street 33
20    | 2nd Street 55
30    | Mystreet 10

[Note]
ID___|Text___|FK_PO_Key
5    | '123' |1
12   | 'abc' |5

[PO_Address]
FK_PO_Key | FK_Address_Key
2         | 10
5         | 30
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL statements, some sample data as DML statements, and desired results.

Comment: It's more of a YES / NO question. Is it even possible.

Comment: Then the answer is "Yes". It's possible. Now if you want to know how, please edit your question.

Comment: Ok nice! Hold on, this might take a few minutes

Comment: @ZoharPeled I hope it's more clear now, what I'm trying to do..

Comment: relevant table? sample data? desired output?

Comment: Adding some sample data